# ffmpeg hangs when using -fflags +genpts

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4, vob

I'm trying to remux a .vob file (which I got using vobcopy) into a mp4 container (mkv would do it as well) using ffmpeg 4.2.4-ubuntu0.1.
Initially the remuxing finished, but I got these errors:

```
[mp4 @ 0x560f9a37e5c0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
```

and several thousand times

```
[mp4 @ 0x560f9a37e5c0] pts has no value
```

---

So I tried fixing it using `-fflags +genpts`:

```sh
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i 'video.vob' -c copy 'video.mp4'
```

After processing around 90000 frames ffmpeg gets somehow stuck (but the CPU keeps running on 100%) and can only terminated using `kill` combined with Ctrl+C.

I tried it with an other .vob file and ffmpeg hanged this time at an other point.

---

When creating the full debug log I noticed that after the program was aborted the output always shows the same last edited frame (92775). Here you can view it: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tbhMmpQwff/

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for the hint. I have now attached the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding the `+igndts` flag:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts+igndts -i 'video.vob' -c copy 'video.mp4'
```

It resulted in some error messages at the point where ffmpeg hung up earlier, but the created video file was fine.

```
[mp4 @ 0x56482f355a00] Invalid DTS: 333993600 PTS: 0 in output stream 0:0, replacing by guess
[mp4 @ 0x56482f355a00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 334018800, current: 334018800; changing to 334018801. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

I'm not sure what caused the problem and what `+igndts` does to fix it, but I'm happy that it works.