# using ffmpeg to fix a mp4 with dropped/skipped frames due to dropped stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

the output stream from my security cameras (EufyCam) will occasionally drop the rtsp stream, sometimes up to 10s of seconds at a time, if the network connection (wifi) signal is poor.

the stream nevertheless gets recorded onto my Synology NAS, and when downloading the clips from the NAS as `.mp4` files, they end up skipping in playback.

For instance when playing, the video will freeze (duplicated frames during the dropped stream) with the audio continuing, and the time stamp in the player will skip ahead in time.

For instance it will skip from `0:00:35` to `0:00:54`, skipping almost 20 seconds.  this causes lots of problems in playback and when using other programs, like Subtitle Edit.

I've tried re-encoding, tried [resetting the pts](https://superuser.com/questions/1607636/ffmpeg-hangs-when-using-fflags-genpts), transcoding, [heuristic measures to delete duped frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088517/remove-sequentially-duplicate-frames-when-using-ffmpeg).

my attempts with ffmpeg generate warnings like "non-montonic DTS in the output stream" or "queue input is backward in time," and though output files are typically generated, nothing provides the output I want, which is to just skip/omit the dropped frames (no skipping ahead in the playback) like the skipped period of time never happened.

if you have unrelated suggestions like hardwiring the cameras, etc, please know my current setup is the best possible given my circumstances.

Ideally the audio would be synced but if not, I wouldn't mind doing this later through some other means.

obviously the formats are quite complex and maybe never meant to handle this kinds of issues, but if there's any way to "fix" this, with ffmpeg or any other software, guidance on doing so would be appreciated.